# Scroll wheel on mouse doesn't work in MS edge after setting overflow: auto in html body

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following css style sheet for a page in my ASP.NET Core MVC project:

```
body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background: linear-gradient(30deg, rgba(121, 110, 255, 0.95) 0%, rgba(33, 200, 122, 0.95) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgba(121, 110, 255, 0.95) 0%, rgba(33, 200, 122, 0.95) 100%);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;}
```

After adding the line `overflow: auto;` the effect has been, that I was not more able to scroll the page vertically using my wheel on the mouse with MS Edge. All other browsers work fine.

There was a thread on that [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/scroll-wheel-and-vertical-scrolling-not-working-in/c6b1d54e-5fdd-4bb9-a2f4-52609fb2009a), but no valid suggestion or help has been provided. This thread is locked.

Any suggestion or workaround?

Comment: Why do you need `overflow: auto;` on the body ? Because normally, it should automatically allow you to scroll whithout it.

Comment: to be able to extend dynamically my gradient on the page. If I don't use overflow, the gradient will repeat somewhere at the bottom of the page and it doesn't look well. Overflow solves the issue, but the mouse wheel doesn't work with Edge!

Comment: Do you want the background to have like a parallax effect (using JS ?), or just to be fixed ?

Comment: It has to be simply fixed

Comment: Ok. I don't have a fix for allowing to scroll, but I think you have a bad approach. Try replacing your `overflow: auto;` by `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: This works fine!!! Thanks a lot Nei. You halped me a lot :-)

Comment: Your welcome ! I'll make an answer for the ones that doesn't want to bother looking comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `overflow: auto;` is usefull only to make the background fixed, since you are applying it to the whole body. (Sidenote : you might want to do `overflow : scroll` instead of `auto`)
But the correct way to make a background fixed is to use `background-attachment: fixed;` :

```css
body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background: linear-gradient(30deg, rgba(121, 110, 255, 0.95) 0%, rgba(33, 200, 122, 0.95) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgba(121, 110, 255, 0.95) 0%, rgba(33, 200, 122, 0.95) 100%);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
resize: both;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I guess the "error" is because your code makes a scrollable element inside the page which is already scrollable. Maybe try clicking your page before scrolling to be shure.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what is going on in your CSS is that you are adding some stuff that is automatically taken care of by the browser. For example:

```
body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background: linear-gradient(30deg, rgba(121, 110, 255, 0.95) 0%, rgba(33, 200, 122, 0.95) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgba(121, 110, 255, 0.95) 0%, rgba(33, 200, 122, 0.95) 100%);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
resize: both;
}
```

I don't think that the `overflow: auto` is necessary and that it was the problem. On a body, there should be no need to add `overflow: auto` as the body normally does it on its own.

Please tell me if this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jason, Nei (see above) has answered my question: background-attachment: fixed; has to be used istead of overflow. This makes the magic.